# Código php para parcelas simples

Tags: php

Tenho este código `php` para mostrar o numero de parcelas, mas ele mostra assim:
Parcele em até 6x sem juros.
Eu quero que ele mostre assim:
Parcele em até 6x de 30 reais.

No caso de 30 reais é só um exemplo, ele teria que dividir o numero total por 6 e mostrar.

O código é esse:

```
<?php
    $vezes = $_product->getData('parcelas');
    echo '<p><small><b>Parcele em até '.$vezes.' X sem juros</b></small><br />';
        for ( $i=1; $i <= $vezes; $i++ ) {
             echo '<small>'.$i.'x de '.$_coreHelper->currency($_product->getFinalPrice()/$i, true, false).'</small><br />';
        }
    echo '</p>';
?>
```

Ele mostra também as parcelas em linhas, mas isso não tem problema.

Como ficaria?

Comment: Pega a variável do preço final divide pelas vezes e usa o number format pra formatar o preço

Comment: como ficaria? eu nao manjo nada de php :\

Comment: Eita deu ruim minha resposta.vou tentar pelo PC...

Comment: Ai estou no PC, vou montar a resposta de novo.

Comment: Postei uma resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode elaborar uma variável para fazer o cálculo e imprimir ela. Como este exemplo:

```
<?php
$vezes = $_product->getData('parcelas');
$calc = $_coreHelper->currency($_product->getFinalPrice()/$vezes, true, false);
echo "<p><small><b>Parcele em até '".$vezes."' X sem juros de '".$calc."'</b></small><br />";
    for ( $i=1; $i <= $vezes; $i++ ) {
        echo '<small>'.$i.'x de '.$_coreHelper->currency($_product->getFinalPrice()/$i, true, false).'</small><br />';
    }
echo '</p>';
?>
```

Creio que deverá resolver seu problema.

Comment: Perfeito! Valeuzão André :D